Setup nginx configuration
I am trying to convert some set of apache rules to nginx.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php

But, So far I came with this Nginx configuration.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /path/to/your/document/root;

    # Serve files from the public directory if they have an extension
    location ~* \.\w+$ {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 break;
    }

    # Route all other requests to server.php
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /server.php;
    }
}

Its not working
how can I fix this

What does this rule RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N] do?

To convert your Apache rewrite rules to Nginx configuration correctly, you need to make sure the logic is correctly translated into Nginx directives. Your existing Nginx configuration is close but needs some adjustments to correctly handle the conditions and rewrites.
This should work:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /path/to/your/document/root;

    # Serve files from the public directory if they have an extension
    location ~* \.\w+$ {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 break;
    }

    # Check if the request is for a directory or file and handle accordingly
    location / {
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
        }
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        # Route all other requests to server.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /server.php;
    }
}

Changed:
The location block with regex ~* .\w+$ handles requests for files with extensions, redirecting them to the public directory.
location ~* \.\w+$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 break;
}

The location / block checks if the request is for a directory or a file. If it is, the request is served normally. If not, it routes the request to server.php
location / {
    if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # Route all other requests to server.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /server.php;
}

You see, by using if statements inside the / location block, we mimic the Apache rewrite conditions checking for directories and files, which prevents unnecessary routing to server.php if the requested resource exists.
Don't forget to reload the config:
sudo systemctl reload nginx
# or
sudo systemctl restart nginx

